# Why Do I Need To Cast This Method Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm learning about inheritance and polymorphism right now and I understand it except for this. Why do I need to cast three.setY() shouldn't it already have access to it since I'm creating an H object that inherits from the G class.

Line 8 is the syntax error.

```java
public class WS2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        G three = new H();
        System.out.println(three);
        three.setX(8);
        three.setY(21); // Syntax Error -> ((H) three).setY()
        System.out.println(three);
    }
}

class G
{
    private int x;
    
    public G()
    {
        x = 3;
    }
    
    public void setX(int val)
    {
        x = val;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + x;
    }
}

class H extends G
{
    private int y;
    
    public H()
    {
        y = 4;
    }
    
    public void setY(int val)
    {
        y = val;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + y + " " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `H` is the class that implements the `setY(...)` method.  but `three` is of class `G` - so if you want to call the method, you need to tell the compiler to treat it like an `H` (otherwise it will not find it) - it's not the same as `setX(..)` since this method is inherited from the parent class (`G`) and it's automatically inherited from `H` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`three` is known at compile time to be reference to a `G`. The type of `three` does not reflect that the referenced object might actually be an `H`.

A `G` has no method `setY` and therefore you cannot call `setY` on a `G` reference.

You can force a runtime check that the referenced `G` is really an `H`; if the check succeeds then you can call `setY`. And if the check fails, you'll get an exception. Which is what you're doing with the cast.

You might object that "it's obvious" that the object in this case is really an `H`, and it does look that way to a human reader.  In other cases, though, it's not so simple - the language rules cater for the general case.

Also, why declare `three` as a reference to a `G` if you want to treat it like an `H`?  Declare it as an `H`. Most other contexts that need a `G` will accept it as such.  It all comes down to the intent of the programmer (and I see this is just an example to explore the language, so there's nothing really to go on to say what would be 'right').